# Android - How do I make a button have a different function after being pressed?

Tags: java, android

So, In my code the user must answer a quick math question and press a button to answer but for the next question it does not check for the second answer only the first. How could you make it where it then checks for the next answer and not the previous one?

primaryText.setText(Questions[0]);

```
    enter.setOnClickListener(

            new Button.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v)

                {
                    if(numberVal.getText().toString().equals("14")) {

                        primaryText.setText(Questions[1]);

                    }

                    if(numberVal.getText().toString().equals("5")) {

                        primaryText.setText(Questions[2]);

                    }

                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: You should move your logic into a separate method and pass in a Question object to that method. This way you can scale it to an arbitrary number of questions without issues. From the looks of it, your code could use some refactoring to make it a bit more object oriented

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
OnClickListener
```

try :

```
MyBtn1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    //do stuff
                }
                else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    //do stuff
                }
                else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL){
                    //do stuff
                }
            return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
boolean questionComplete = false;
enter.setOnClickListener(

        new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v)

            {
                if(!(questionComplete)){
                if(numberVal.getText().toString().equals("14")) {
                    questionComplete = true;
                    primaryText.setText(Questions[1]);

                }
                }
                else {
                if(numberVal.getText().toString().equals("5")) {

                    primaryText.setText(Questions[2]);

                }
               }
            }
        }
);
```

This would make it so that after the first question is complete, it would display the second question. It would only work for two questions though

Comment: While this solves the case for a single question, it is still not scaleable and seems to be pretty bad practice.